# My npm command does not work "Cannot find module 'internal/errors'"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

My npm command does not work anymore I uninstall and re install nodejs many times and still getting the same issue, so here is my console output, how can I fix this?

```
C:\Users\pirat>npm install
        module.js:529
            throw err;
            ^

        Error: Cannot find module 'internal/errors'
            at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
            at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
            at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
            at evalmachine.<anonymous>:36:16
            at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pirat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:11:1)
            at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
            at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)

        C:\Users\pirat>
```

Comment: Can you post your _package.json_? Might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I re-install node version 6.11 and updated npm now is all working :)